# Post to Form with XML Media Type in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to post form data with Spring. That form data is `XML` format. But every time I try posting, I get a 415 error.

```
public void setFormData(String name, Integer age){
  String url = "https://my.example.com/path/";

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

  Form form = new Form();

  form.set("name", name);
  form.set("age", age);

  HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(form, headers);
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  restTemplate.put(url, request);

}
```

Since the above didn't work, I went and implemented this:

```
public void setFormData(String name, Integer age){
  String url = "https://my.example.com/";

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

  MultiValueMap<String, Object> params= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
  params.add("name", name);
  params.add("age", age);

  HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(map, headers);
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
  Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxbMessageConverter = new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter();
  List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
  mediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
  jaxbMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(mediaTypes);
  messageConverters.add(jaxbMessageConverter);
  restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

}
```

XML that accepts the request:

```
<resource path="/path">
  <method name="POST">
   <request>
    <representation mediaType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
     <param name="name" style="query" type="xs:string">
     <param name="age" style="query" type="xs:int">
    </representation>
   </request>
  </method>
</resource>
```

But I still got the 415 error. I've also tried setting the MediaType to     `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` in the Java code but I get the 415 error. How can I post to XML form using Spring? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your `ContentType` to `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` in the first blob. The 2nd blob of code that messes with Http message converters is useless. I'm not sure what the `Form` is that you're populating - `MultiValueMap` should work as well.
2. Use POST method, not PUT. Either `postForEntity` or `postForObject` should do it.
3. Truth be told, I've never seen a Spring controller declared in XML like yours above, and I'm a Spring committer. Have you considered using annotations? The world stopped using XML Spring config in 2011.